# Using Variables to Change Directories

Tags: batch-file

I am new to writing batch files. I want to create a batch file that will allow me to change 2 directories using variables. What I have below is what I have thus far. Any ideas?

```
@echo off
S:
cd AAA
set /p CLIENTCODE=CLIENTCODE?
cd %CLIENTCODE%
pause
set /p SCHEMANAME=SCHEMANAME?
cd %SCHEMANAME%
pause
```

Comment: in the search box in the upper right hand corner type: batch change directories

Comment: The code looks okay. So what is the problem exactly?

Comment: If, for some reason, you are under the impression that your code is not working, I would first make sure that the `%CLIENTCODE%` directory given by the user is actually located inside of the `AAA` directory, and that the `%SCHEMANAME%` directory is actually inside of the `%CLIENTCODE%` directory, because that's where you're telling the code to look for those.

Comment: The line containing just `S:` changes the current directory to the last used directory on drive `S:`. This can be root of drive `S:`, but also any other directory on this drive. Replace the 2 lines `S:` and `cd AAA` by `cd /D "S:\AAA"` which changes the current directory definitely to `S:\AAA`. Run in a command prompt window `cd /?` for details on parameter `/D`.

Comment: Mofi,  I want the AAA as the clientcode that the user enters and then the next prompt is the schemaname which consists of the following entry 5H..so what I want the batch program to do is start at the S: then after the entries CD to AAA and then once the user enters the 5H to then go another level down using a combo of the AAA and 5H (AAA5H) ..hope that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

Try following batch code:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "ClientCode=AAA"
set "SchemaName=5H"
:UserPrompt
cls
set /P "ClientCode=Enter client code (default: %ClientCode%): "
set /P "SchemaName=Enter schema name (default: %SchemaName%): "
if not exist "S:\%ClientCode%\%ClientCode%%SchemaName%" goto InputError
cd /D "S:\%ClientCode%\%ClientCode%%SchemaName%"
endlocal
goto :EOF

:InputError
echo.
echo Client code "%ClientCode%" or schema name "%SchemaName%" is not valid.
set "InputAgain=Y"
set /P "InputAgain=Enter data again (Y/N)? "
if /I "%InputAgain%" == "Y" goto UserPrompt
if /I "%InputAgain%" == "YES" goto UserPrompt
endlocal
```

This batch file first defines defaults for client code and schema name making it possible for the user to simply hit key <kbd>RETURN</kbd> or <kbd>ENTER</kbd> when defaults are okay.

Next the window is cleared and the user is prompted for client code and schema name. The input of the user is not validated at all.

A very simple check is made if the appropriate directory (or file) exists.

The current directory is changed if a directory according to entered data exists.

If the directory does not exist, the user is asked if data input should be repeated in case of a typing mistake. The user can input `Y` or `YES` in any case to redo data input. Otherwise the batch script exits without changing the directory.

There is no real effort made on validating user input strings and verifying if the entered strings really lead to a directory and not a file.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `cls /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`